# Discord.js How to edit role every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to edit role color every 5 or 10 seconds by `setInterval`, And the problem is i have to repeat the command to change color. I don't want to repeat the command just one command it edit the role color every 5 seconds.

**Example:**

!test = choice 1 color

and i have to repeat the command to choice between colors

!test = choice between 2 colors

!test = choice between 3 colors ...

```js
if(message.content === prefix+'test'){
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
    var colors = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9'];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "role name");
    setInterval(() => {
        role.edit({
            color: colors[random]
        })
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired property name to search against was wrong, it should be

```
message.guild.roles.find("The name of the role to find", "name");
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
message.guild.roles.find(roleVal => roleVal.name === "The name of the role to find");
```

Comment: i changed my Question becuase i don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
var colors = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9'];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "role name");
    setInterval(() => {
        role.edit({
            color: colors[random]
        })
    }, 5000);

});
```

Just put it on ready event and it will change it automatically if is that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(message.content === prefix+'test'){
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
    var colors = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9'];
    for(let i = 0; i<= colors.length;i++){
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "rolename");
    setInterval(() => {
        role.edit({
            color: colors[i]
        })
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

i tried this and it is working fine....

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer, even if it is ok, try to explain your approach, and in your case, as there is another one similar, exposed the cons and pros of your answer.